# C# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Language on Front and Admin Area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two areas in my project, `Admin` and `Client`.

RouteConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { language = "en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Testing.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Current results:

```
[✓] localhost
[✓] localhost/en-us
[✓] localhost/zh-hk
[✗] localhost/admin
[✗] localhost/client
```

I hope I can do something like this:

```
localhost - Home Page (Default Language)
localhost/en-us - Home Page (English)
localhost/zh-hk - Home Page (Traditional Chinese)
localhost/admin/en-us - Admin Area Home Page (English)
localhost/admin/zh-hk - Admin Area Home Page (Traditional Chinese)
localhost/client/en-us - Client Area Home Page (English)
localhost/client/zh-hk - Client Area Home Page (Traditional Chinese)
```

Comment: have you register route for area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register areas before generic route register

Add `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` before your generic route,

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { language = "en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "Testing.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Your admin area registration,

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { language = "en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Client Area Registration,

```
public class ClientAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Client";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Client_default",
            "Client/{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { language = "en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```